# Simpleinjctor get instance based on generic type

Tags: ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

I need to convert `Ninject` to  `SimpleInjector` Implementation.

I have the following code

```
public T Resolve<T>()
{
    // IKernel kernel - is the global declaration
    return kernel.Get<T>();
}
```

I want the equivalent to this for simple injector

I have tried

```
public T Resolve<T>()
{
    // SimpleInjector.Container kernel - is the global declaration
    return kernel.GetInstance<T>();
}
```

But this throws an error due to `T` not being a class as it is a generic type.

I can't cast the method to strictly take and return `T` as class because it is an interface implementation.

Any Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add a generic type constraint to your Resolve method:

```
public T Resolve<T>() where T : class
{
    return kernel.GetInstance<T>();
}
```

or call the non-generic GetInstance overload:

```
public T Resolve<T>()
{
    return (T)kernel.GetInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: I will give that second one a try